# How to call a before_filter with various parameters depending on the controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two controller :

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :get_model
  # Actions
end

class MyOtherController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :get_model
  # Actions
end
```

In my `ApplicationController`, I have a function that I use to get a certain model :

```
def get_model
  @model = Model.find(params[:model_id])
end
```

However, the parameter that will hold the model id is not the same for both controllers.

How can I make this work without repeating myself ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`before_filter` can accept a Proc or a lambda as its first parameter.

Refactor your `get_model` function so it accepts and id :

```
def get_model(id)
  @model = Model.find(id)
end
```

Then call your before_filter with a lambda, and pass the corresponding id :

```
before_filter lambda { get_model(params[:whatever_id]) }
```